# Calling GetOpenFileName by Interop Marshalling isn't supported in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, interop, marshalling

Calling GetOpenFileName(); function isn't supported in UWP??

i test that code. (code in Checked Answer)

[Using GetOpenFileName instead of OpenFileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088227/using-getopenfilename-instead-of-openfiledialog)

things i changed is only 'CharSet.Auto' to 'CharSet.Unicode'
('CharSet.Auto' was not compiled in UWP Environment)

but it not working.

```
        OpenFileName ofn = new OpenFileName();

        ofn.structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(ofn);

        ofn.filter = "Log files\0*.log\0Batch files\0*.bat\0";

        ofn.file = new String(new char[256]);
        ofn.maxFile = ofn.file.Length;

        ofn.fileTitle = new String(new char[64]);
        ofn.maxFileTitle = ofn.fileTitle.Length;

        ofn.initialDir = "C:\\";
        ofn.title = "Open file called using platform invoke...";
        ofn.defExt = "txt";

        bool bResult = false;
        if (bResult = LibWrap.GetOpenFileName(ofn))
        {

        }
```

GetOpenFileName() result (bResult) is only 'false'.

i can't use FilePicker because of restriction of directing custom folder path.

Comment: It is just one of many legacy winapi functions that were retired in UWP.  Most basic issue with it, beyond it already being obsolete for the past 11 years, is that it does not observe the restrictions stipulated in the appx manifest.  Use its substitute, the [FileOpenPicker class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).  Use the WACK tool to get a warning about it.

Comment: Is there no way to Specify Custom path in FileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation Property? i know the existence of FileOpenPicker, but as i know, FileOpenPicker couldn't specify the start path.

Comment: You need the dll in windows Comdlg32.dll (common dialogs) .  See pinvoke : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comdlg32/GetOpenFileName.html  So you project has to be built in 32 bit mode and not 64 bit mode.

Comment: The net library methods in a lot of cases are just wrappers that call windows dlls like Comdlg.dll often with less visibility or different default options then what users really need.  Often just casting Net Library properties will expose more properties.

Comment: i read that pinvoke site, but that site was only vb code and, i think this code is almost like the code i tested. however, i tested x86 compile, but it not worked.

Comment: @jdweng This is UWP which is why that function can't be called. 32 or 64 bit makes no difference. Not possible from either bitness process. Also, the 32 doesn't mean what you think it does. Note that a 64 classic desktop app will routinely load comctl32, kernel32, user32, comctl32, etc. The 32 was added when MS moved from 16 to 32 bit and persists to this day.

Comment: You cannot use a custom start location in a file picker in UWP. UWP establishes a sandboxed environment, and the files and directories available to your application are restricted. You certainly won't be able to access the system's root directory, as you attempt in your code, irrespective of the API you use. If you need that, you will have to leave UWP behind, and write a classic desktop application.